# MachineKey.Protect/Unprotect breaks when enabling 32 bit applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I am using the .net `MachineKey.Protect` method to encrypt a token in one application and the corresponding `MachineKey.Unprotect` method to verify the token in a different application.

Everything works fine until I have to set **Enable 32-Bit Applications** to **True** in IIS to get some other code to run. Then the `MachineKey.Unprotect` method throws an exception

> Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.

I have tried this with both applications in the same app pool, and both in different app pools, and all combinations of the setting. Anything apart from the **Enable 32-Bit Applications**  set to **False** in all instances results in the error.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: I can only guess that changing the bitness of the code also has an impact on the decryption. Keep the bitness the same when encrypting and decrypting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my problem was to specify a fixed machine key in both versions of **machine.config**

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

and

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

adding this element in `<system.web>`

```
<machineKey validationKey="C3A9A590C67C27D96650E4EF5F586943A641187F5655052C3EB0BAC852CAA7D094D21376D4C8D91E989A36D9D2BF868B3CA63493AC6358B0415C1E34E1B8C346"
        decryptionKey="C6E83A1393A826814BE889349CBFDFBFCDC9318313616EDD" 
        validation="HMACSHA512" decryption="AES" />
```

I am still unsure as to why this works. IIS was set to use a server wide machine key in IIS Manager. The clue to solving the problem came when I tried to search for the existing keys in the machine.config files.

You still need to ensure that both applications are running in the same mode.

You can even *encrypt* in one application running with **Enable 32-Bit Applications** set to **True** and *decrypt* in another with **Enable 32-Bit Applications** set to **False** if you set the machine key in the applications' web.config

**EDIT**

Since trying to deploy it to a server running Server 2008 we found it was necessary to amend 4 machine.config files:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Still don't really know why

Comment: Hopefully, that's not *literally* the value that you're using, that you've now shared with the world.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So what's my web application? I'll be impressed if you can tell me. (and it isn't actually those values btw )

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know for sure, but the `Enable 32bit applications` changes the working process bitness.

On 32bit system it does nothing.

On x64 system, when it is set to `false` (default), IIS worker processes work in x64 mode and use 64bit environment (path, registry, etc). But when this setting is set to `true`, related worker processes are launched in x86 mode, and use 32bit (syswow) environment - settings, executables, com components, etc - may disappear or different versions may show up. That's because syswow environament uses different system paths, different registry locations, etc.

I wouldn't be suprised to see that the encryption keys stored for normal and syswow environments are different. Whatever you were using for encrypting, try launching that in 32bit mode and retry.

Also, `Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.` doesnt tell much, really. Have you checked stacktrace or innerexceptions?

Comment: Stack trace is no good. Doesn't leak any info about cryptographic error

Answer (score 0):

Switching from 32bit to 64bit apps will result in a different machine.config being loaded in, which may cause problems if the machine.config specifies different values for the machinekey, up to and including differences in the key, or in how the default key is generated.